# Adding custom attributes to script tag via Scripts.Render

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, requirejs

In my MVC application I would like to use [require.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#usage). I am trying to use following way;

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/require")
```

in require.js documentation it is documented as;

```
<!--This sets the baseUrl to the "scripts" directory, and
    loads a script that will have a module ID of 'main'-->
<script data-main="scripts/main.js" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
```

So I need to set **data-main="scripts/main.js"** section in MVC part.

How can I achive to add extra attributes via Scripts.Render function?

Answer (score 3):

Found out needs to use following way;

```
  @Scripts.RenderFormat("<script type=\"text/javascript\" data-main=\"/JavaScript/main.js\" src=\"{0}\"></script>", "~/bundles/require")
```